# Site build fails due to Format() not being available on Type toml.LocalDate

Tags: go, hugo

When I am building a site on Hugo using a pipeline, the build constantly fails with the following error:

```
Error: Error building site: 
failed to render pages: render of "home" failed: execute of template failed: template: index.html:22:11: executing "main" at <partial "session-dates.html" .>: 
error calling partial: "/github/workspace/layouts/partials/session-dates.html:4:20": 
execute of template failed: template: partials/session-dates.html:4:20: 
executing "partials/session-dates.html" at <.Site.Params.current_startDate.Format>: can't evaluate field Format in type toml.LocalDate
```

The error is happening on the `current_startDate`, and `current_endDate` values, where it's saying there is no Format function available for the type. The config is:

```
baseURL = "..."
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "..."
summaryLength = 20
relativeURLs = true

[params]
    current_startDate = 2021-10-10
    current_endDate   = 2021-12-04
```

Then the template code is:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 dates">
        <span class="long-dates">
            {{ .Site.Params.current_startDate.Format "January 2, 2006" }} —
            {{ .Site.Params.current_endDate.Format "January 2, 2006" }}
        </span>
        <span class="short-dates">
            {{ .Site.Params.current_startDate.Format "01/02/06" }} —
            {{ .Site.Params.current_endDate.Format "01/02/06" }}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried looking at the docs and other examples and the configuration seems to be correct, so I assume there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: @gopher so what format needs to be used in order to do this then? Does it need to be the full date type like `2021-10-10T14:15:59-06:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is running into this issue, for some reason specifically on the pipeline https://github.com/chabad360/hugo-gh-pages this doesn't work. When testing locally the original format I had works for both building and previewing at the command line.

The fix is to give the full datetime format, so for my example above that is:

```
baseURL = "..."
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "..."
summaryLength = 20
relativeURLs = true

[params]
    current_startDate = 2021-10-10T14:15:59-06:00
    current_endDate   = 2021-12-04T14:15:59-06:00
```

This configuration builds as expected locally, and in the pipeline.